How should I show that an approximate solution for $x(t)$ for $t=O(\epsilon^{-1})$ is the following?
Homework problem: Consider the modified van der Pol equation $\ddot{x}+\epsilon(x^4-1)\dot{x}+x=0, 0<\epsilon<<1$, with initial conditions $x(0)=a$ and $\dot{x}(0)=0$, where $a$ is a constant. Show that an approximate solution for $x(t)$ for $t=O(\epsilon^{-1})$ is $x(t)=\frac{8^{1/4}\cos t}{(1+(\frac{8}{a^4}-1)e^{-2\epsilon t})^{1/4}}$.
Here's my work:
By using the method of multiple scales, the solution to this equation can be written in the form $x(t)=X(t, \eta)$, with $\eta=\epsilon t$, where $X(t, \eta)$ satisfies the partial differential equation $\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial t^2}+X+\epsilon(2\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial\eta\partial t}+(X^4-1)\frac{\partial X}{\partial t})+\epsilon^2(\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial\eta^2}+(X^4-1)\frac{\partial X}{\partial\eta})=0$, with initial conditions $X(0, 0)=a$ and $\frac{\partial X}{\partial t}(0, 0)+\epsilon\frac{\partial X}{\partial\eta}(0, 0)=0$.
By writing $X(t, \eta)$ in the form of $X(t, \eta)=X_{0}(t, \eta)+\epsilon X_{1}(t, \eta)+O(\epsilon^2)$ and equating the coefficients of the powers of $\epsilon$ to zero, we get $\frac{\partial^2 X_{0}}{\partial t^2}+X_{0}=0$ for $X(t, \eta)=X_{0}(t, \eta)$ in the zeroth-order equation $O(1)$.
Note that the auxiliary equation is $\lambda^2+1=0$, which implies that $\lambda=\pm i$.
Hence, the solution to the equation for $X_{0}(t, \eta)$ can be expressed as $X_{0}(t, \eta)=A(\eta)e^{it}+\bar{A}(\eta)e^{-it}$, where $A(\eta)$ is a function of $\eta$ only, $\bar{A}(\eta)$ is its complex conjugate, and the initial values are given as $A(0)=\bar{A}(0)=\frac{1}{2}a$.
Also, $A(\eta)$ satisfies the equation $2\frac{dA}{d\eta}+2A^3\bar{A}^2-A=0$. By writing $A=p^{1/2}e^{i\alpha}$ where $p$ and $\alpha$ are real functions of $\eta$, we have that $\frac{dp}{d\eta}=p(1-2p^2)$ and $\frac{d\alpha}{d\eta}=0$.
My question is that, from here, how should I show that an approximate solution for $x(t)$ for $t=O(\epsilon^{-1})$ is $x(t)=\frac{8^{1/4}\cos t}{(1+(\frac{8}{a^4}-1)e^{-2\epsilon t})^{1/4}}$?
