How should I find this particular solution from this ODE?
Homework problem: Show that the solution to the differential equation of $\frac{d^2x_{1}}{d\tau^2}+x_{1}=-\frac{8^{3/4}}{4}\alpha^2\cos 3\tau+\frac{8^{5/4}}{16}(3\sin 3\tau+\sin 5\tau)$ is $a_{1}\cos\tau+\frac{1}{8^{3/4}}[\frac{\alpha^2}{\sqrt{2}}(\cos 3\tau-\cos\tau)+\frac{1}{6}(32\sin\tau-9\sin 3\tau-\sin 5\tau)])$ with the initial conditions of $x_{1}(0)=a_{1}$ and $x'_{1}(0)=0$.
Here's my work:
I tried to solve the ODE by using the method of undetermined coefficients but the answer didn't match what I've got. Although, I've got the homogeneous equation of $x_{h}(\tau)=a_{1}\cos\tau$ because $x_{h}(\tau)=C_{1}\cos\tau+C_{2}\sin\tau$ where $C_{2}=0$ after substituting the initial condition of $x_{1}(0)=a_{1}$. However, for the particular solution, I've formed the equation of $x_{p}(\tau)=A\cos 3\tau+B\sin 3\tau+D\sin 5\tau$ and so $x_{p}'(\tau)=-3A\sin 3\tau+3B\cos 3\tau+5D\cos 5\tau$ with $x_{p}''(\tau)=-9A\cos 3\tau-9B\sin 3\tau-25D\sin 5\tau$. After I used the direct substitution of $x_{p}(\tau)$ and $x_{p}''(\tau)$ into the given ODE, I didn't get the correct answer. What's wrong in here?

You have made an error somewhere when plugging in your initial conditions. You should not have obtained $C_2 = 0$ when you apply the initial condition $x_1(0) = a_1$.

Yes, I've noticed it.

While it's tempting to exclude $\sin\tau$ from $x_h(\tau)$, the desired solution includes such a term and thus it cannot be correct to neglect it. The error is that, while $x_1'(0)=x_h'(0)+x_p'(0)=0$, your particular solution has $x_p'(0)=3B+5D$ which will generally not be zero. That is, your full solution should be of the form $$x_1(t)=C_1\cos \tau+C_2\sin\tau+A\cos 3\tau+B\sin 3\tau+D\sin 5\tau$$
with $A,B,C$ such that the ODE is satisfied along with the initial conditions $$x_1(0)=C_1+A=a_1,\quad x_1'(0)=C_2+3B+5D=0.$$

So what should be the form of the particular solution of $x_{p}(\tau)$?

@Purity The particular solution is in the form you provided. The issue was with the homogeneous solution, not the particular solution.

So you're saying that the form of the homogeneous equation $x_{h}(\tau)=C_{1}\cos\tau+C_{2}\sin\tau$ was wrong?

What should be the form of the homogeneous equation then? Is it just $x_{h}(\tau)=C_{1}\cos\tau$?

I disagree, your answer says the opposite @Semiclassical. The OP has the correct form of the homogeneous equation and your answer reflects that. The OP has simply made a computation error when applying the initial conditions.

You're right---I got my mental wires crossed in my replies. The error was in excluding $\sin \tau$ from the homogeneous solution, i.e.., the homogeneous solution should be $x_h(\tau)=C_1\cos \tau+C_2\sin\tau$ with $C_2\neq 0$.

Many thanks to Semiclassical and Maths Matador for the help!

@Semiclassical, may you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5012775/how-should-i-show-that-an-approximate-solution-for-xt-for-t-o-epsilon-1 ? I need help on this problem.
